# Create/Use property to get Session variable C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASPX Web Forms control that imports from another project the Person class.

```
public partial class cuTest : System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

There I have created in that control a property for an object session and a method to populate that session.

```
    public Person person
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Session["Person"] == null)
            {
                Session["Person"] = new Person();
            }
            return Session["Person"] as Person;
        }
    }

    private void crearPago()
    {
        this.person.name = "Max";
        this.person.surname = "Ford";
    }
```

Now when I want to call it from the page that contains that control.
`var x = cuTest.person;` I need to check if it's not empty since this can't be null. How can I do that?

Comment: Why is your Person class doing anything at all with Session? It sounds like your class is trying to do too much stuff.

Comment: What would make this `Person` object empty? If you mean `null`, then that won't happen because you instantiate it if it's null whenever you get it.

Comment: @I want to populate in a Session object data from that control and then be able to use that Session from others webforms of the same proyect but only have 1 instance. Session["Person"] = name.text and then use that Session. I don't know if im explaining it correctly.

Comment: Why you want to have this functionality in a UserControl? You can always have a static class to provide such methods/properties

Comment: @TasosK. This sounds very good to implement, could you provide an example on how to implement it? Or where I could find an optimal way to implement it?

Comment: "I need to check if it's not empty since this can't be null" having trouble understanding what this means

Comment: @JohnWu The idea, probably not the right thing, lets say I need a few data from page1 to page2, I save them in a Session object (which is created in a static class so I can use them from my proyect) so I can retrieve/use them in page2, when I get it, before doing what I have to do, I need to check that the Session is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a static class `Web` that I add there any properties that are useful throughout the application.

One thing that differs is that the `Request`, `Response` and `Session` objects are not directly available. So, I have 3 helper functions that return the current `Request`, `Response` and `Session` objects, if available.

So, a `Person person` property would be like that:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace MyWebApp
{
    public static class Web
    {
        private static HttpRequest request
        {
            get
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current == null) return null;

                return HttpContext.Current.Request;
            }
        }

        private static HttpResponse response
        {
            get
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current == null) return null;

                return HttpContext.Current.Response;
            }
        }

        private static HttpSessionState session
        {
            get
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current == null) return null;

                return HttpContext.Current.Session;
            }
        }

        public static Person person
        {
            get
            {
                // Here you can change what is returned when session is not available
                if (session == null) return null;

                if(session["Person"] == null) {
                     session["Person"] = new Person();
                }

                return session["Person"] as Person;
            }
            set
            {
                // Here you can change how to handle the case when session is not available
                if (session == null) return;

                session["Person"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, in your `Page` or `UserControl` code, you can write

```
// get
var x = MyWebApp.Web.person;
// set
MyWebApp.Web.person = x;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just for curiosity, can I add a set property? So that after I have finally used the Session, to set Current to null?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply check if the name/surname is null or empty with:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.name);
```